# How to modify column in power query

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

How can I remove comma from the cell in column 33 and 23 in power query?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Transform section** above the formula bar you see the **Replace Values** function. You can use the function to replace "," with "". That's it.

But after removing the first 2 rows and promoting the 3rd row as headers you can directly convert 33 and 23 into decimal numbers and a thousands or decimal separator would be recognized depending on your regional settings.

Comment: or replace , with nothing (a null) to remove it

Comment: Thank you for the effort, and sir how can I get October 15 2022 from column 33 row 1 in column instead of serial number( or in new column if possible).